# date computations in a PCL

Tags: c#, date, portable-class-library, gregorian-calendar

I see that the GregorianCalendar class is not available in a C# Portable Class Library.  I want to do some calendar calculations -- how many months, weeks, and days, have passed between two dates.

Is my best bet to roll my own?

Comment: Have you considered [Nodatime](http://nodatime.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Try Noda Time: http://nodatime.org/

It is a date/time library for .NET that has a portable version available.

Answer (score 0):

Generally date/time operations can be performed directly from the DateTime construct.  If you find something missing from the DateTime object, you could try including System.Globalization.dll in with your application.  Search within C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET and chose the correct version.

The GregorianCalendar class itself suggests that its advantage over the DateTime class is its support of ERAs (B.C., A.D.).  It shares most of its code with DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Protip: if something is not available in PCL and there is no good, tested library for that - why not try to port it to PCL ? It shouldn't be tough - I've just looked in `.NET Framework` source code and it seems it's not tightly coupled to anything outside PCL.  [GregorianCalendar source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/calendar.cs,dc2444cc5e0d0f08)